# JavaScript: GreaseMonkey, How to insert an element

Tags: javascript, greasemonkey

I am using greasemonkey to change a website his content.

I want to add an LI element with JavaScript after de LI item of Dogs, it is not my website so I am not allowed to insert some ID's into the LI items.

```
<div id="main-nav">
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav brand-left">
        <li><a href="/cars">Cars</a></li>
        <li><a href="/bikes">Bike</a></li>
    </ul>
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav brand-right">
        <li><a href="/cats">Cats</a></li>
        <li><a href="/dogs">Dogs</a></li>
        NEW LI ELEMENT HERE
    </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var ul = document.querySelector('.nav.navbar-nav.brand-right');
var newli = document.createElement('li');
// do what you need to the new li, including giving it an id if you want
ul.appendChild(newli);
```

That should do it

Comment: Yeah this works! But how do I add an element inside the `li` (`<a href="/about">About</a>`)

Comment: `newli.innerHTML = '<a href="/about">About</a>';` is one way

Answer (score 1):

> it is not my website so I am not allowed to insert some ID's into the LI items.

JavaScript and so Greasemonkey are necessarily executes client-side only. This means that any changes made with this language will only be visible to you. You are therefore allowed to modify the page as you see fit and do absolutely anything you want.

```
var new_li = document.createElement("li")
document.getElementsByClassName("brand-right")[0].appendChild(new_li);
```

Comment: I know that it is only clientside, and that it is only visible for me.

Comment: @Thom Not sure what you was talking about.